# retrieve custom post image through widget

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, post-thumbnails

My custom post has featured image. I need to retrieve  it  through widget. I am using get_the_post_thumbnail. But it is not working. Except this the rest of the widget is working fine.

Here is the short excerpt of my code

```
<?php
class Employee extends WP_Widget {
    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        $widget_ops = array( 
            'classname' => 'team_widget',
            'description' => 'Enter Empolyees to show them on front page.',
        );
        parent::__construct( false, 'Show Empolyees', $widget_ops );
    }    

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];     
        if ( ! empty( $instance['photo'] ))  {              
            echo $args['before_image']
            .$instance['photo'] 
            .$args['after_image']               
        }    
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }    

    public function form( $instance ) {   
        if ( post_type_exists( 'employee' ) ) :              
        $args = array(
                    'type'                  => 'post',
                    'child_of'              => 0,
                    'parent'                => '',
                    'orderby'               => 'name',
                    'order'                 => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty'            => 1,
                    'hierarchical'          => 1,
                    'exclude'               => '',
                    'include'               => '',
                    'number'                => '',
                    'taxonomy'              => 'department',
                    'pad_counts'            => false,
                    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
                    'post_type'             => 'employee',
                    'tax_query'             => array(
                                                    array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'department',
                                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                                        'terms' => 'department',
                                                    )
                                        ) 
                ); 
            $posts = get_posts( $args );
            if ( ! empty( $posts ) && ! is_wp_error( $posts ) ) :
                ?>

                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'photo' ); ?>" 
                        value="<?php echo esc_html(get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ) ?>"
                        <?php checked( $instance['photo'], get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ); ?> >Show Photo
                    <br>
                </p>
                <?php
                endif; // chk posts based on terms.
        endif;//chk post type endif.
    }


    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();

        $instance['photo'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['photo'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['photo'] ) : '';         

        return $instance;
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calls to `get_the_post_thumbnail` do work, the problem is how what you're doing with the result:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'photo' ); ?>"
    value="<?php echo esc_html(get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ) ?>"
    <?php checked( $instance['photo'], get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ); ?> >
```

You can't put image HTML tags inside of another tags attributes, that's not valid html. You're also using an escaping function that strips out HTML `esc_html`.

This will never work, and makes little sense:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="<img src="example.com/img.png">">
```

Instead consider something that generates valid markup, such as this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="test"><img src="example.com/img.png"></label>
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testid" name="test">
<label for="testid"><img src="example.com/img.png"></label>
```

[See here for how to create labels for checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293588/how-to-create-an-html-checkbox-with-a-clickable-label), and remember to use `esc_attr` to escape your `value`

Comment: Then what would be the value of the checkbox? What would be the value of $instance['photo'] ? This is my print_r($instance) result : Array ( [photo] => ) . If I check the box and save array does not take the  value<img/>.
Is there any other way to retrieve the post thumbnail so that I can save its value?

Comment: I want to pass the result of the get_the_post_thumbnail as the value of my checkbox value to save as $instance['photo'].

Comment: I solved the problem somehow. Would you please tell me if it is the right way or wrong way. 

<?php $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' ) ); ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'photo' ); ?>"  value="<?php echo $image_url ?>"
<?php checked( $instance['photo'], $image_url ); ?> >Show Photo

Results this 

<input type="checkbox" name="widget-employee[7][photo]" value="http://localhost/site/wp/wp-theme-dev/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/medium.jpg" checked="checked">

 I am not sure if it is the right way to do this.

Comment: You're going to need to update your question to provide some context as to what the purpose of this is, why you're trying to build it, and what the goal is. I believe I've answered your question, but what you wrote and what you actually want are not the same thing